# Searching for an element in a Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, indexing

I have an array of object (JSONized). Something like this :

```
popUpList = [{
    "id":1,
    "Name":"My Pop Up",
    "VideoUrl":"www.xyz.com/pqr",
    "AddToBasketUrl":"www.abc.com?addtoBaketid=1",
    "addedToBasket": true
},
{
    "id":2,
    "Name":"My 2nd Pop Up",
    "VideoUrl":"www.xyz.com/mno",
    "AddToBasketUrl":"www.abc.com?addtoBaketid=2",
    "addedToBasket": false
}]
```

My situation is a clip can be either added from he pop up or the main page. So, I need to edit the JSON object when something is added to basket from the page.

I tried using $.inArray() and similar methods. i reckon either I am not doing it the right way or missing something. Or, this cannot work for JSON objects and I have to loop through every object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (what `$.inArray` is) does need the element to search for and returns its index.

If you need to search for an element you don't know before, you will need to loop manually (Libs like Underscore have helpers):

```
var idToSearchFor = …;
for (var i=0; i<popUpList.length; i++)
    if (popUpList[i].id == idToSearchFor) {
        // do something
    }
```

If you want to build an index for faster accessing popups, you can do that as well. It also has the advantage of being unambiguous (only one element per id):

```
var popUpsById = {};
for (var i=0; i<popUpList.length; i++)
    popUpsById[popUpList[i].id] = popUpList[i];

if (idToSearchFor in popUpsById)
    // do something with popUpsById[idToSearchFor]
else
    // create one?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Managed to solve the issue.function popUpVideoIndex(clipBinItemId) {
    var itemIndex = -1;
    $.each(popUpVideoList, function (i, v) {
        if (v.ClipId == clipBinItemId) {
            itemIndex = i;
            return itemIndex;
        }
    });

    return itemIndex;
} 
this does not process the whole loop but loops till it matches the criteria. My JSOn object is not quite small but this does the work for now. Thanks a lot for your help :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to search explicitely, you can access each value in your object by using:

```
    vat id = "1";

    // this given example wont work for you bec. of your structure
    // but its all about the idea.

    var objectOne = yourJsonObject[id];

    // You can also append them
    var myValue = yourJsonObject.address.zip;
```

And similiar on any other item of the fetched first object.

For that I would create a custom search function which would look like that:

```
$.each(popUpList, function(i, v) {
    var entryYouWantToFind = "addedToBasket";
        if(v[entryYouWantToFind])
        {
            // do your stuff here.
        }
    }
});
```

I hope I could give you the hint.